# I am getting this error in react : JSX element 'h1' has no corresponding closing tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to raect. I created react project and when I am creating new component I am gettinng this error in all the components. I this there is no mistack in the code but don't know why I am getting this error.

code :
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

ReactDom.render( < h1 > Hello World < /h1>, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Remove spaces in the tags `<h1> Hello World </h1>`

Comment: Yes. I tried that. but after saving it automatically space is getting added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per enve comment - remove the spaces, add react into the namespace:

```
import React from „react”
```

Check the file extension (should be *.jsx)

This most likely will solve your problem.

If it still persists you will have to disable editor on save action and check code for prettier rules.

Comment: Thanks. file extension was js after writting .jsx it worked.